# Modify/remove existing inapp subscription products

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I'm searching for a way to modify/remove existing inapp subscription plans I created in google play for an already released app, that in the current version has no BILLING permission (and so no inapp purchases), it seems that there is no way to remove or event modify an "active" inapp subscription also if it's available only in the "alpha" channel of google developer console.

The only suggestion I got googling around is to remove the application and recreate it (I cannot do it since it's a released application with thousands of users).

I've also searched a lot for some google developer support address to ask for this issue, but all I found in the official android documentation is IRC/Forums and a link to stack overflow!

I've seen there is a similar question from 2014, not equal, but similar, anyone knows if google added a way to remove *UNRELEASED* inapp subscriptions in the last three years?

iOS subscriptions can be modified and removed without problems until release...

Comment: Just remove In-App integration from your application & upload new version. Play store will not effect your app if you have supbscription plans in play console.

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel it doesn't work. I've published a new beta (google developer beta channel) without BILLING permission, but I still see my subscriptions in the console and I cannot remove them.

Comment: I have same issue in my app, First i upload app with in-app billing; then i removed in-app billing from app. It works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is still no way of doing this.

Comment: I've been able to chat with a "google android support guy" and he told me the same...